# Are there custom properties in openapi 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-php

We have php-swagger which generates developer documentation in open api 3.0 format.

There was a task - to make OTHER documentation based on the generated api-docs.json, for clients with a limited number of routes, static (without the ability to send requests). Just make a stripped down new openapi 3.0 format json file

It turns out that you need to somehow mark the annotations in the code that these are annotations for OTHER documentation. And create a new json file.

The problem is that I don’t know how to mark the routes at the annotation level in the php code, so that there would be some FEATURE in the description of the route, thanks to which I could parse api-docs.json and extract routes with this feature from it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use vendor extensions https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/guide/common-techniques.html#vendor-extensions

These are part of the standard but ignored so you can use them in whatever way you like.